# HTTP request methods in HTML

Tags: html, http

Does HTML support the **direct** programming of custom HTTP requests?

For example, is there is a way to write HTML code that directly **instructs** the browser to make a **custom** GET / PUT / POST / DELETE request with custom headers, body and parameters (query string) to a particular endpoint?

Comment: you can define form action and method, but can't define request headers without js `form action="/action_url" method="get"`

Comment: Other than forms, HTML doesn't make custom requests directly. You would need to employ your requests with JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

In general, HTML can only trigger GET requests. The exception are forms which allow you to make POST requests as well.

You can't have a custom body (forms can encode the data in form fields using one of three encoding methods).

You can't set custom headers.

If by "parameters" you mean "query string", then you can type what you like in a URL (within the constraints of the URL data format).

All those things are possible using JavaScript (via APIs like `fetch` and `XMLHttpRequest`).